# Better way to Sort a List by any property

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, expression, func

My method receives all DataTables parameters to sort table by column clicked. I call this method from controller of each page list.
I'm looking for a better way to do this like a generic method for all types: **string**, **int**, **decimal**, **double**, **bool** (**nullable** or **not**). But I can't find it.

My current code:

```cs
public List<T> OrderingList<T>(List<T> list, DataTablesParam model)
{
    var iColumn = model.Order.FirstOrDefault().Column;
    var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(model.Columns.ToArray()[iColumn].Data);
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var final = Expression.Property(param, property);

    var isDirAsc = model.Order.FirstOrDefault().Dir.Equals("asc");

    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
    {
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(final, param).Compile();
        return isDirAsc ? list.OrderBy(lambda).ToList() : list.OrderByDescending(lambda).ToList();
    }
    else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(int))
    {
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>(final, param).Compile();
        return isDirAsc ? list.OrderBy(lambda).ToList() : list.OrderByDescending(lambda).ToList();
    }
    else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
    {
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(final, param).Compile();
        return isDirAsc ? list.OrderBy(lambda).ToList() : list.OrderByDescending(lambda).ToList();
    }
    else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(decimal))
    {
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, decimal>>(final, param).Compile();
        return isDirAsc ? list.OrderBy(lambda).ToList() : list.OrderByDescending(lambda).ToList();
    }
    else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(double))
    {
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, double>>(final, param).Compile();
        return isDirAsc ? list.OrderBy(lambda).ToList() : list.OrderByDescending(lambda).ToList();
    }

    return list;
}
```

---

I want to do something like this: (But this code doesn't work)

```cs
public List<T> OrderingList<T>(List<T> list, DataTablesParam model)
{
    var iColumn = model.Order.FirstOrDefault().Column;
    var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(model.Columns.ToArray()[iColumn].Data);
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var final = Expression.Property(param, property);

    var isDirAsc = model.Order.FirstOrDefault().Dir.Equals("asc");

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, dynamic>>(final, param).Compile();
    return isDirAsc ? list.OrderBy(lambda).ToList() : list.OrderByDescending(lambda).ToList();
}
```

---

Comment: Why not provide a lambda to grab the sorting property and use `IComparer<T>` for the comparison?

Comment: You would basically use this existing method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549422(v=vs.100).aspx - `list.OrderBy(item => item.SomeProperty, Comparer<PropertyType>.Default);`  - You could make a method that provided the comparer by default.

Comment: maybe create another generic method CreateLambda<Tout,TIn> which returns Expression.Lamda<Func<TOut,TIn> . 
you can then get this CreateLambda's MethodInfo with reflection and cast it to your TIn and Tout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better way to do this. I had to do 3 steps:

1 - Add the package "Linq Dynamic" in project:

```
Install-Package System.Linq.Dynamic.Library
```

2 - Import the package in Class:

```cs
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
```

3 - Order list by the string name of property:

```cs
list.OrderBy(stringPropertyName);                 //asc
list.OrderBy(stringPropertyName + " descending"); //des
```

It work perfectly for me.

Comment: Note that this works pretty similar to my solution but with the overhead of having to add a dependency. I originally wanted to propose using Linq Dynamic but decided against for sake of simplicity, and to show you how to make your attempt work.

Answer (score 1):

You can just call the `Enumerable.OrderBy` method using reflection. That way, you don’t have to know the type at compile-time. To do that, you just need to get the method, and create a generic method using the property’s type:

```
private IEnumerable<T> Sort<T> (List<T> list, string propertyName)
{
    MethodInfo orderByMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().First(mi => mi.Name == "OrderBy" && mi.GetParameters().Length == 2);

    PropertyInfo pi = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
    MethodInfo orderBy = orderByMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), pi.PropertyType);

    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    Delegate accessor = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(param, pi), param).Compile();
    return (IEnumerable<T>)orderBy.Invoke(null, new object[] { lst, accessor });
}
```

Note that I abstracted out the stuff about your model to keep this method generic enough. It can basically sort by any property on a list by just specifying the property name. Your original method would then look like this:

```
public List<T> OrderingList<T>(List<T> list, DataTablesParam model)
{
    var iColumn = model.Order.FirstOrDefault().Column;
    string propertyName = model.Columns.ToArray()[iColumn].Data;

    return Sort(list, propertyName).ToList();
}
```

Comment: There will be a performance hit compiling the Lambda.  That may or may not matter in this case.  If it matters, the compiled lambda can be cached.

Comment: @EricJ. That’s a good point; the function still leaves some room for optimization. One should also look up the `orderByMethod` just once.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond just not being very generic, your solution also requires a lot of extra memory because you're copying the list with LINQ. You can avoid this using `List.Sort`.

I would do:

```
static void SortBy<T>(List<T> list, MemberInfo member, bool desc)
{
    Comparison<T> cmp = BuildComparer<T>(member, desc);
    list.Sort(cmp);
}

static Comparison<T> BuildComparer<T>(MemberInfo member, bool desc)
{
    var left = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var right = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

    Expression cmp = Expression.Call(
        Expression.MakeMemberAccess(desc ? right : left, member),
        "CompareTo",
        Type.EmptyTypes,
        Expression.MakeMemberAccess(desc ? left : right, member));

    return Expression.Lambda<Comparison<T>>(cmp, left, right).Compile();
}
```

Comment: This doesn’t work for multiple reasons: If you meant to use `IComparer<>`, then the method is called `Compare` and you would need an actual comparer instance to call this on. If you meant to use `IComparable<>`, then you won’t get a `Comparer<T>` back which you could pass to the `Sort` method. And finally, the type argument you need to pass `IComparer<>` or `IComparable<>` would be the member/property type and not the list item’s type, as you want to compare the values of those properties.

Comment: Thanks, I typoed `IComparable` as `IComparer`. It should work now.

Comment: Then, as per my comment above, the type argument would need to be the member’s type (not the list item type `T`), and also `IComparable<>.CompareTo()` returns an int, not a `Comparer<>` object.

Comment: Risk of doing it by memory, not testing in an IDE. Sigh.

Comment: Haha, yeah, that seems to work a lot better. It doesn’t seem to work with string properties though. You could call the method like this though: `typeof(IComparable<>).MakeGenericType(member.PropertyType).GetMethod("CompareTo")` (assumes that `member` is now a `PropertyInfo`).

Answer (score 0):

It's works fine for me: (Thanks @Poke)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31393168/5112444

My final method:

```cs
private IEnumerable<T> Sort<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, string propertyName, bool isAsc)
{
    MethodInfo orderByMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().First(mi => mi.Name == (isAsc ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending") && mi.GetParameters().Length == 2);

    PropertyInfo pi = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
    MethodInfo orderBy = orderByMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), pi.PropertyType);

    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    Delegate accessor = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Call(param, pi.GetGetMethod()), param).Compile();
    return (IEnumerable<T>)orderBy.Invoke(null, new object[] { list, accessor });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested method almost works. You need to change two things in order to make it work:

```
public List<T> OrderingList<T>(List<T> list, DataTablesParam model)
{
    var iColumn = model.Order.FirstOrDefault().Column;
    var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(model.Columns.ToArray()[iColumn].Data);
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
    Expression final = Expression.Property(param, property);

    // Boxing of value types
    if (property.PropertyType.IsValueType) {
        final = Expression.MakeUnary(ExpressionType.Convert, final, typeof(object));
    }

    var isDirAsc = model.Order.FirstOrDefault().Dir.Equals("asc");

    //                                     VVVVVV
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(final, param).Compile();
    return isDirAsc
        ? list.OrderBy(lambda).ToList()
        : list.OrderByDescending(lambda).ToList();
}
```

1. Instead of using `dynamic` use `object`, since every type is an `object`.
2. If you have a value type, you need a boxing operation, i.e. you must cast the value to object `(object)i`. This is done with a unary convert operation:

   ```
   Expression final = Expression.Property(param, property);
   if (property.PropertyType.IsValueType) {
       final = Expression.MakeUnary(ExpressionType.Convert, final, typeof(object));
   }
   ```

Note also that final is declared explicitly as `Expression`, since the expression type might change from property to unary expression.

Comment: This case throw this exception: Unable to cast the type **System.Int32** to type **System.Object**. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types @Olivier